# Using Code <> As Actual Text

Tags: html, dom

Really having trouble with this and can't find any results on it.

I want my html text to utilize the carrots <> for some of my text.

Specifically for a navbar menu item.  But I can't seem to build it without activating the text as an actual div.

I want it to say "< Dev>" without using quotes or spaces, but it when I take the quotes/spaces away it activates it as a div.  How do I keep the entire message "< Dev>" without turning it into a div item?

E.g:

```
<p> Welcome to my <Dev> portfolio</p>
```

Also what is the term used to override reserved code functions as text?  Will help me research answers for other issues too.  Like when using & as text and not as code.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: You can see which characters can be created using this character table - https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=oct&unicodeinhtml=dec&htmlent=1

Comment: I just googled "Use greater than sign in HTML" and I got lots of good results about exactly this subject. I don't want to be disparaging but I have a hard time believing that you've been unable to find _any_ results.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `<p> Welcome to my &lt;Dev&gt; portfolio</p>`

You can find a list of HTML character codes [Here](https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the html unicode values for those characters instead.

Welcome to my &60Dev&62 portfolio

Sorry it looks like this forum reads those unicode characters and prints them correctly. Add # signs at the after the & characters to get the html code.